# How to i iterate over a table which has input tags inside the td

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

```
<div id="tableDiv">
<table  id="mytable">
  <tr> 
    <td><input type="text" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" ></td>
  </tr>
</table></div>
```

how to i iterate over this table and store the values inside an array variable,

additional rows will be added to this table using an add row button , how to i determine the the no of rows and how to i store the values inside the varibles, such that i will be able to retrieve values of each rows at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you to store all  input the values inside table  as array !

Html

```
<div id="tableDiv">
  <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<button onclick="print()">Print</button>
```

Js

```
 const tableEle = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable input')
// Creating an empty array
  let array = [];
// Function to add all values from inputs and store in array variable 
  function createArr() {
    tableEle.forEach(ele => {
      array.push(ele.value.trim())
    })
  }
// Finally this function when called creates and logs in console 
  function print() {
    createArr()
    console.log(array)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get some idea from this code.

here is and JsFiddle -> [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/x2oc9bvd/91/)

```js
function myFunction() {
var value1 = document.getElementById("val1").value; //get first inputBox value
var value2 = document.getElementById("val2").value; //get second inputbox value
  
if(value1 !== "" && value2 !== ""){ //check input boxes are filled

  var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); //Start here creating the table
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    
  cell1.innerHTML = value1;
  cell2.innerHTML = value2;  
  }else{
    alert("please fill all input boxes")
  }
}

function getValues(){
//search and get the value from table
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  
  var findValue = document.getElementById("findVal").value;
  
  if(findValue){
 
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
      for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
        
        if(findValue === table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML){
            alert("value found: "+table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
          return false
        }          
      }
    }
  }else{
    alert("please fill input boxes")
  }
}
```

```css
.main{
  display:flex;
}

.btn{
   margin-left:2px;
}
.input{
   width:100px 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div>
    <input class="input" type="text" id="val1" onfocus="this.value=''">
    <input class="input" type="text" id="val2" onfocus="this.value=''">
  </div>

  <div class=btn>
     <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> 
  </div>
  
  <div class=btn>
      <button type="button" onclick="getValues()">find</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
     <input class="input" type="text" id="findVal">
  </div>

</div><br>

  <div>
  
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
  </div>
```